# DELETE statement is not using INDEX on table and executing for long time

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

There is one huge table which is having 25M records and when we try to delete the records by manually passing the value it is using the INDEX and query is executing faster.
Below are details.

```
MySQL [(none)]> explain DELETE FROM isca51410_octopus_prod_eai.WMSERVICE WHERE contextid in ('1121','1245','5432','12412','1212','7856','2342','1345','5312','2342','3432','5321');
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | DELETE      | BIG_TABLE | NULL       | range | IDX_BIG_CID   | IDX_BIG_CID | 109     | const |   12 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
```

But when we try to pass the values by using select query it is not using index and query is executing for more time.
Below is the explain plan.

```
MySQL [(none)]> explain DELETE FROM DATABASE1_1.BIG_TABLE WHERE contextid in (SELECT contextid FROM DATABASE_2.TABLE_2);
+----+--------------------+------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table            | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | DELETE             | BIG_TABLE        | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 25730673 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | TABLE_2          | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |       10 |    10.00 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Here DATABASE_2.TABLE_2 is a table where the values will change everytime and row count will be less than 100.
How to make use of index IDX_BIG_CID on table DATABASE1_1.BIG_TABLE for the below query

```
DELETE FROM DATABASE1_1.BIG_TABLE WHERE contextid in (SELECT contextid FROM DATABASE_2.TABLE_2);
```

Comment: Use WHERE EXISTS instead of WHERE IN. Or JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `IN ( SELECT ... )`.  Use a multi-table `DELETE`.  (See the ref manual.)